# Icon's size in Custom Layout Android

Tags: android, xml, icons, android-imageview

I want to change the size of my app's icon in Custom Title bar. Here's my code so far:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:background="#000000">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My styles.xml file is:

```
  <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
    </style>

   <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">30dip</item>

    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>
```

This produces an icon on the left of the title bar but how can I change the icon's size ? I want the icon to be a little larger.

Comment: why not use [Android asset studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks for that @thepoosh. I didn't know it. But can you suggest anything on my specific problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you should just set specific DP attributes for your ImageView.  Stick with DP, and is will scale fine on all devices.  Like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```